# Python - Pandas: Split-Divide DataFrame with two Totals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has two totals like this:

```
v1  v2  x1  x2  t1  t2
5   5   8   3   10  11 
4   9   2   1   13   3 
10  10  8   3   20  11
```

How can I convert it something like this

```
v1   v2   x1   x2  t1  t2
50%  50%  72%  28% 10  11
30%  70%  66%  33% 13   3
50%  50%  72%  28% 20  11
```

No rounding is needed.Totals T1 and T2 can either remain or be deleted

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use basic division:

```
a = df.iloc[:, :4].values
b = np.repeat(df.iloc[:, 4:].values, 2, axis=1)

pd.DataFrame(a / b, columns=df.columns[:4])
```

```
    v1        v2        x1        x2
0  0.500000  0.500000  0.727273  0.272727
1  0.307692  0.692308  0.666667  0.333333
2  0.500000  0.500000  0.727273  0.272727
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) for division and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df.filter(like='v').div(df['t1'], axis=0),
                df.filter(like='x').div(df['t2'], axis=0)], axis=1)
print (df)
         v1        v2        x1        x2
0  0.500000  0.500000  0.727273  0.272727
1  0.307692  0.692308  0.666667  0.333333
2  0.500000  0.500000  0.727273  0.272727
```

If want also total columns:

```
df = pd.concat([df.filter(like='v').div(df['t1'], axis=0),
                df.filter(like='x').div(df['t2'], axis=0),
                df[['t1','t2']]], axis=1)
print (df)
         v1        v2        x1        x2  t1  t2
0  0.500000  0.500000  0.727273  0.272727  10  11
1  0.307692  0.692308  0.666667  0.333333  13   3
2  0.500000  0.500000  0.727273  0.272727  20  11
```

Answer (score -1):

You can manually divide the columns that suit your needs, for example:

```
df['v1'] = (df['v1'] / df['t1']) * 100
```

Comment: This is not practical for large number of columns

Comment: I was just showing a basic example not knowing assuming number of columns and column names.